# Unicode-Math and \not

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

I am using [`unicode-math`](https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) to typeset equations. Since I am using a non-standard keyboard layout, I prefer to enter most math symbols with their unicode representation. However, the the `\not` operator sometimes produces a `6` as output. Consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
  \(\not ∈ \; \not\in \quad ≠ \; \not = \; \neq \quad ≮ \; \not<\)
\end{document}
```

Which produces—using XeLaTeX—the following output.

[image: Curious behaviour of not]

Is this a bug of the `unicode-math` package or is it because of some encoding problems?

Comment: On texlive 2018, I don't get a 6, but the slash is poorly positioned on the first symbol.

Comment: The 6 was due to a bug in unicode-math which has been resolved. But if you want good symbols you should better use the commands as then some extra processing is involved which maps them to the correct glyphs. See https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/363.

Comment: Always use `\notin`, `\neq`, and `\nless` to avoid these problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have an old version of `unicode-math` (the “6 problem” has been solved months ago). However, even for the last version, `\not ∈` will not yield the expected result; help `unicode-math` to:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\NewNegationCommand{∈}{\notin}

\begin{document}
  \(\not ∈ \; \not\in \quad ≠ \; \not = \; \neq \quad ≮ \; \not<\)
\end{document}
```

[image]